# PAYEE_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED: The merchant account is restricted

Tags: angular, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am integrating a PayPal payment gateway in a angular website and I have tested PayPal integration with sandbox client id & secret id and it is working fine, but when I changed to live credentials it gives me

```
Uncaught Error: PAYEE_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED: The merchant account is restricted.
```

I am using a personal account of Paypal for the integration, do I need to create a business account of PayPal for integration?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This error means the account receiving the funds (the payee) cannot receive funds. If your account is the one receiving the payment, upgrade it to a business account. If another account is receiving the payment, the owner of that account should review information regarding the restriction in their [www.paypal.com](http://www.paypal.com) account interface, and contact PayPal with any questions

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this problem, the account needs to be verified properly.

Please check if you have any limitations by clicking this URL (make sure you are logged in first):

https://www.paypal.com/disputes/

If you have any limitations, you will need to solve it all.
https://www.paypal.com/restore/dashboard